# Get immediate parent tag with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've researched this question but haven't seen an actual solution to solving this. I'm using BeautifulSoup with Python and what I'm looking to do is get all image tags from a page, loop through each and check each to see if it's immediate parent is an anchor tag.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
html = BeautifulSoup(responseHtml)

for image in html.findAll('img'):
    if (image.parent.name == 'a'):
         image.hasParent = image.parent.link
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: These docs would imply that your pseudocode is pretty much correct: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to check [`parent`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent)'s [`name`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#name):

```
for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    if img.parent.name == 'a':
        print "Parent is a link"
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <body>
...     <a href="google.com"><img src="image.png"/></a>
... </body>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> img = soup.img
>>> 
>>> img.parent.name
a
```

---

You can also retrieve the `img` tags that have a direct `a` parent using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('a > img')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! By using `img.parent.name`, that will always be the immediate parent no matter what right?